# apt update not working

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to update my machine but it isn't working. The version I'm using is:

> LSB
> Version:  core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Release:   22.04
> Codename: jammy

I tried running `sudo apt udpate` and the output is this:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy/ InRelease          
Hit:3 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:5 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease     
Get:6 https://zotero.retorque.re/file/apt-package-archive ./ InRelease [2 153 B]
Hit:7 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Err:9 http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy/ Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 137.222.10.189 80]
Hit:10 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease  
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Get:12 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease [2 718 B]
Err:12 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://deb.anydesk.com/dists/all/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE
```

I have looked for the problem but I couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is EOL - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  thus references to that release (*impish*) should not have been added on a *jammy* system as you'll only risk adding *unfixed* code to your system, they should be removed as adding them wasn't a *bright* thing to do (*lowering security for jammy/22.04*).

Comment: Your sources are a mess. You have mismatched sources from different releases and you've added a bunch of sources that are probably incompatible with your system. Don't add sources unless you're sure they won't break your system. Adding sources changes the catalog of available software which will cause problems if any sources have incompatible packages or dependencies. The default sources will not have these incompatibilities. So leave your sources alone unless you absolutely need to alter them. In most cases there are alternative ways to install software without altering sources.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. Someone helped me installing Ubuntu, so I don't know what should be there. I checked the post you comment @guiverc but don't know what to do. Should it be `sudo ppa-purge ppa:impish-security`

Comment: The references to *impish* (or 21.10) I saw in your paste related to http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu where the issue was reference to an EOL release (*impish*).  That line should just be removed.  Me I'd just use `vi` or `vim` to edit/remove it, or just add a "#" at the start of the line so it's treated as a comment (ie. disabled), but it's up to you. If using a desktop system you can use GUI tools too - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  but it's not a PPA or 3rd party repo. so ppa-purge isn't required, disable or remove it.

Comment: The link to https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu/ is to a set of instructions on using a PPA and not a source for packages & should be accessed via a browser - not added to your sources.list file(s); at least that's what I see....

Comment: I removed the impish file and now the problem is with http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy/ Release. I'll keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: I spoke about that too if you look ^ (*or tried to in my own way*)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it says there's no release file. It doesn't work.

Comment: It should be removed; it's a set of instructions (*from what I saw & mentioned*) and shouldn't have a release file as that would be incorrect usage of what it's for.

Comment: All of the sources that don't end in `ubuntu.com` are sources that were manually added.

Comment: Yeah, but when you follow the instructions the last one is adding a repository and that's where it says there's no release file.

Comment: What instructions are you referring to? Just because you're following written instructions doesn't mean they are good. I could write instructions to withdraw all of your money as cash and feed it to a paper shredder, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't follow those.